# Appengine error object has no attribute '_key'

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GAE database entity that looks like this:

```
class Notification(db.Model):

    alert = db.StringProperty()
    type = db.StringProperty()
    status = db.StringProperty(default="unread", choices=set(["unread", "read"])) 
    created  = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    entity = db.StringProperty()
    record = db.ReferenceProperty(model.RecordModel)
    actor = db.ReferenceProperty(model.Profile)
    account = db.ReferenceProperty(model.Account)
```

... and I create an entity like so:

```
notify = model2.Notification(account=account)
notify.alert = message
notify.type = "reminder"
notify.actor = actor
notify.record = record
notify.put()
```

This call raises an error ***'Notification' object has no attribute '_key'***

```
nquery = db.Query(model2.Notification).filter('account =', self.session.account).order('-created')            
for n in nquery:
  try:
    _dict = {}
    _dict['serverID'] = str(n.key()) #- raises error!
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
nquery = Notification.all().filter('account =', self.session.account).order('-created')
```

Comment: That raises the same error. I've even tried renaming the entity to "Notify" to avoid any sort of possible naming conflict with GAE classes, but still raises same error. When I comment out "n.key()" the error disappears.  this is mind boggling, because I really need to get that entity key!

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?  There may be clues there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out! The "entity" property in my Notification class is causing some sort of naming conflict in python appengine. Changing the name removes the "error object has no attribute '_key'" error. Go figure!